# LinkedIn OAuth returns unclear error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, omniauth

In response to an oauth request, LinkedIn redirects user back to my server with the following parameters:

```
GET /auth/linkedin/callback?error=server_error&error_description=f228ff35d9f7f99ee891ff1e9b056a7a2e4b8429b84de8d7&state=the+authorization+server+encountered+an+unexpected+condition
```

Moreover, according to [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2), error_description is "A URL-encoded textual description that summarizes error.", which is not the case here.

Here's the original request:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=************&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress&state=cc167e16fcc8039277cae38dc02d08bf526c955ceb403513
```

How can I find out the actual reason for the failure?

My stack:

- Rails 4.2.3
- omniauth 1.2.2
- omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 0.1.5

Comment: If this is happening every time, can you provide the actual code the fires up the request?

Comment: added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar issue, and it was caused by a trailing space in the username field on the LI OAuth form.

I'm not sure why it didn't happen on other sites with LI Oauth access, but someone from LI has been able to validate it for us. This issue should be resolved very soon (Or so we've been promised)

Answer (score 0):

In many cases this issue can be resolved by generating a new authentication key for your application on LinkedIn.

Comment: thanks but this doesn't help. I wonder why LinkedIn are not clearly specifying the failure reason